# kubectl get pod READY 0/1 state

Tags: kubernetes

I am following a lab on Kubernetes and Mongodb but all the Pods are always in 0/1 state what does it mean? how do i make them READY 1/1

```
[root@master-node ~]# kubectl get pod
NAME                                 READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
mongo-express-78fcf796b8-wzgvx       0/1     Pending   0          3m41s
mongodb-deployment-8f6675bc5-qxj4g   0/1     Pending   0          160m
nginx-deployment-64bd7b69c-wp79g     0/1     Pending   0          4h44m
```

kubectl get pod nginx-deployment-64bd7b69c-wp79g -o yaml

```
[root@master-node ~]# kubectl get pod nginx-deployment-64bd7b69c-wp79g -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-07-27T17:35:57Z"
  generateName: nginx-deployment-64bd7b69c-
  labels:
    app: nginx
    pod-template-hash: 64bd7b69c
  name: nginx-deployment-64bd7b69c-wp79g
  namespace: default
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: nginx-deployment-64bd7b69c
    uid: 5b1250dd-a209-44be-9efb-7cf5a63a02a3
  resourceVersion: "15912"
  uid: d71047b4-d0e6-4d25-bb28-c410639a82ad
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx:1.14.2
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
    resources: {}
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: kube-api-access-2zr6k
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  preemptionPolicy: PreemptLowerPriority
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - name: kube-api-access-2zr6k
    projected:
      defaultMode: 420
      sources:
      - serviceAccountToken:
          expirationSeconds: 3607
          path: token
      - configMap:
          items:
          - key: ca.crt
            path: ca.crt
          name: kube-root-ca.crt
      - downwardAPI:
          items:
          - fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            path: namespace
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2021-07-27T17:35:57Z"
    message: '0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node-role.kubernetes.io/master:
      }, that the pod didn''t tolerate.'
    reason: Unschedulable
    status: "False"
    type: PodScheduled
  phase: Pending
  qosClass: BestEffort
```

kubectl describe pod nginx-deployment-64bd7b69c-wp79g

```
[root@master-node ~]# kubectl get pod nginx-deployment-64bd7b69c-wp79g -o yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2021-07-27T17:35:57Z"
  generateName: nginx-deployment-64bd7b69c-
  labels:
    app: nginx
    pod-template-hash: 64bd7b69c
  name: nginx-deployment-64bd7b69c-wp79g
  namespace: default
  ownerReferences:
  - apiVersion: apps/v1
    blockOwnerDeletion: true
    controller: true
    kind: ReplicaSet
    name: nginx-deployment-64bd7b69c
    uid: 5b1250dd-a209-44be-9efb-7cf5a63a02a3
  resourceVersion: "15912"
  uid: d71047b4-d0e6-4d25-bb28-c410639a82ad
spec:
  containers:
  - image: nginx:1.14.2
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    name: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8080
      protocol: TCP
    resources: {}
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount
      name: kube-api-access-2zr6k
      readOnly: true
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  enableServiceLinks: true
  preemptionPolicy: PreemptLowerPriority
  priority: 0
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  serviceAccount: default
  serviceAccountName: default
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
  tolerations:
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/not-ready
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  - effect: NoExecute
    key: node.kubernetes.io/unreachable
    operator: Exists
    tolerationSeconds: 300
  volumes:
  - name: kube-api-access-2zr6k
    projected:
      defaultMode: 420
      sources:
      - serviceAccountToken:
          expirationSeconds: 3607
          path: token
      - configMap:
          items:
          - key: ca.crt
            path: ca.crt
          name: kube-root-ca.crt
      - downwardAPI:
          items:
          - fieldRef:
              apiVersion: v1
              fieldPath: metadata.namespace
            path: namespace
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2021-07-27T17:35:57Z"
    message: '0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node-role.kubernetes.io/master:
      }, that the pod didn''t tolerate.'
    reason: Unschedulable
    status: "False"
    type: PodScheduled
  phase: Pending
  qosClass: BestEffort
[root@master-node ~]# kubectl describe pod nginx-deployment-64bd7b69c-wp79g
Name:           nginx-deployment-64bd7b69c-wp79g
Namespace:      default
Priority:       0
Node:           <none>
Labels:         app=nginx
                pod-template-hash=64bd7b69c
Annotations:    <none>
Status:         Pending
IP:
IPs:            <none>
Controlled By:  ReplicaSet/nginx-deployment-64bd7b69c
Containers:
  nginx:
    Image:        nginx:1.14.2
    Port:         8080/TCP
    Host Port:    0/TCP
    Environment:  <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from kube-api-access-2zr6k (ro)
Conditions:
  Type           Status
  PodScheduled   False
Volumes:
  kube-api-access-2zr6k:
    Type:                    Projected (a volume that contains injected data from multiple sources)
    TokenExpirationSeconds:  3607
    ConfigMapName:           kube-root-ca.crt
    ConfigMapOptional:       <nil>
    DownwardAPI:             true
QoS Class:                   BestEffort
Node-Selectors:              <none>
Tolerations:                 node.kubernetes.io/not-ready:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
                             node.kubernetes.io/unreachable:NoExecute op=Exists for 300s
Events:
  Type     Reason            Age                   From               Message
  ----     ------            ----                  ----               -------
  Warning  FailedScheduling  2m53s (x485 over 8h)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node-role.kubernetes.io/master: }, that the pod didn't tolerate.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to have only one server for the K8s cluster. In a typical K8s cluster, the master, or the control plane, is usually kept separate from the servers running workloads. To this effect, it has a 'taint', which is basically a property that repels pods. With the taint in place, pods cannot be scheduled on the master.

You can see this information in the 'status.conditions.message' element in the `kubectl get pod` output:

```
message: '0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had taint {node-role.kubernetes.io/master:}, that the pod didn't tolerate.'
```

Pods can define tolerations, which allow them to be scheduled to nodes that have the corresponding taints. That mechanism is explained in detail within the docs: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/taint-and-toleration/

The toleration config should look something like this (untested):

```
tolerations:
- key: "node-role.kubernetes.io/master"
  operator: "Exists"
  effect: "NoSchedule"
```

In your case, it may be easier to use approach mentioned in [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61809595). Specify an explicit `nodeName: master` element in your pod definitions. This should skip the taint mechanism and allow your pods to be scheduled.

Another option is to remove the taint from the master node, as discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43147941

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply but I didn't understand what exactly should I do? Do I need to configure something to define the worker server nodes somewhere? Or should I disable taint on the master? I have read the discussions you suggested but they are not very clear

Comment: @BattistisCiccioRossi I've outlined three approaches here; you can pick one and proceed with it. The first is to add a toleration config to your pod definition. The second is to explicitly specify a node name in your pod definition. The third is to remove the taint from the master. Any of these approaches should resolve the issue you're facing.

Comment: Ok now I understand
thank you very much